# Ugly look on custom error page on chat because of request to HTTP resource

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, ssl

I was visiting some transcripts from a chat room and then I found a link to another room which was removed. On that custom error page, I found two main issues and one was caused by another main issue.

This issue can be found in the custom error page shown, because the room is either deleted or not existed at all.

Issues

#### 1. The topbar overlays the *Object moved to here* message whereas *here* is a link, but it needs much effort to click on because of the topbar.

[image]

#### 2. The dropdowns are not loading.

Once clicked, it shows the div and pretend like loading but then suddenly went and hide.

[image]

### Blame http

When I checked the console, it shows an issue that it makes a request to `http://chat.site` and it presents *Access control allow origin is not present in that resource.*

## On Stack Overflow

[image]

## On chat meta Stack Exchange

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Something* was wrong in the HTTPS redirect code that cause some HTTP URLs to not be correctly shuffled over to HTTPS. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

This has been fixed.

Comment: But the links are still being created as HTTP?

Comment: @Catija Shouldn’t be. Are they?

Comment: Yep. I have a report here that talks about it... both user-created and mod-created links to chat rooms are still serving up HTTP links. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/306915/automatic-comments-for-moderator-and-user-created-chat-rooms-are-still-referring. This one was just created today: https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/11165/how-to-discuss-that-i-have-codependent-behavior#comment44583_11165

Comment: @Catija No, are new links (say, after about 4pm NYC time today) being generated as http? :)

Comment: Ah! Hmmmm... I don't know! Let me go make one and see. :P

Comment: They are :D YAY! I guess this solves my problem, too.