# Automatic comments for moderator and user created chat rooms are still referring to rooms as http rather than https

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, chat, moderator-tools

I became aware today that when a chat room is created by a moderator or user moving comments to chat, the link to the chat room is `http://` instead of `https://`, which means that some attempts to visit the room fail.

From my comments pane:

> [image]

Can this be fixed so that the comments point, correctly, at `https://`?

Comment: I'm aware that the old chat messages won't be fixed, but future ones could be :D

Comment: I've mentioned this already on the ['canonical' HTTPS thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/299979/295232).